# Extracting values from facebook json response

Tags: ios, json, swift, facebook-graph-api

I have the following JSON response from FB:

```
result {
"age_range" =     {
    min = 21;
};
email = "ddsdasddsadas@gmail.com";
gender = male;
id = xxxxxxxxx;
name = "a b";
}
```

I extract each of the elements using

```
let name: String? = result["name"] as? String
```

This works fine, however I don't know how to extract the `min` and `max` fields from the `age_range`. I tried using 
`let min: String? = (result.valueForKey("age_range")).valueForKey("min")` however this returns a null pointer exception.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget those silly type annotations. They do more harm than good.

And never use `valueForKey` to parse JSON, just use key subscription.

From the FB documentation `min` is clearly an integer.

```
if let ageRange = result["age_range"] as? [String: Int], min = ageRange["min"] {
    print(min)
}
```

Comment: One question, why do you use the if statement here. is it to check the type? I'm more of a java programmer and we don't really use if when assigning values to variables, that's why I'm a bit confused, sorry if its a stupid question

Comment: `If let` is the usual and safe way to unwrap optionals. If one of the keys `age_range` and `min` doesn't exist, the if clause is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if let age_range = result.valueForKey("age_range") as? NSDictionary {
let min: String? = age_range["min"] as? String // or as! Int if integer
}
```

Comment: `min` will always be `nil`.